# How can I have webpack bundle my css file?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Currently I am serving it as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
```

This works well because there is not CSS flicker.  It is loaded before bundle.js.

How can I tell webpack to put it in bundle.js so I can remove the above line?

Can I simply import it at the entry point for webpack?

```
import F1Apex from './css.css';
```

Or does it need a special loader?

Is this good practice?

This is for an Express / React app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it simply by writing:

```
import './css.css'
```

at the top of react component to which you wish to add css.

In webpack you can add loader in:

```
module:{
 loaders:[
 ...,
 {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
 ]
}
npm install --save-dev css-loader
```

or one other way is to add css in your react component 
example:

```
<h1 style ={{margin:'20 0 0 0',color:'red'}}>Hello</h1>
```

This works for me. Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: I have many React components but only 1 css file.  Can I just import all from my root React component?

Comment: Actually you should have different styles for different components. That is one of the purposes of React

Comment: yes.you can import css file on index.js (where u are mounting ur react to html/where document.getElementById() is) and it will work for all components. bootstrap also work same way.

Comment: don't I have to install a special loader or is it included with Webpack

Comment: that i have mention in the ans. see if that can help